# How to calculate the SUM of any number of COUNTS

Tags: mysql, count

I'm wondering if it is possible to totalize all products of the amount of scores for each photo multiplied by their score type factor in one SQL query?

Example:

```
t = total : my aim, the total score for each photo
c_foo = count score type foo = the amount of scores for each photo with the score type name = foo 
c_bar = count score type bar = the amount of scores for each photo with the score type name = bar
m_foo = foo factor
m_bar = bar factor
```

The number of different score types is arbitrary.

```
t = c_foo * m_foo + c_bar * m_bar + … + c_last * m_last
```

My initial idea is to use the following table structure:

- http://twitpic.com/840ctk/full

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.id, st.name, st.factor, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM s2p_photo p
LEFT JOIN s2p_score s 
LEFT JOIN s2p_score_type st 
GROUP BY p.id, st.name
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

I receive the name, factor and sum of photos but I'm not able to do the math.

- http://twitpic.com/840ctk/full

I have no idea if `UNION` is feasible here.

Is my table structure ok? Does anyone of you has a clue?

PS: Sorry I'm not able to post images; please open them manually in your browser :(

Comment: I want to help you out here, but it's kind of unclear what you're looking for. Do you want the total number of rows for that `id`? That's what you're getting. Is "total" really just a subset? At any rate, your table structure image is expired. Try using http://imgur.com for your images. Could you post some sample data and what you want the result set to be?

Comment: I cannot access your images. Why not put them someplace free and open?

Comment: Sorry for the pain with the images. I've uploaded them to twitpic and they are working for me. MAybe the URL of the images is restricted to my personal twitter account... :(

Alternative URLs are:
http://twitpic.com/840acy/full for the structure and http://twitpic.com/840ctk/full for my best result.

anyway i think you already answered my question. thankks very much again.

Comment: Posting the minimum SQL for the tables (CREATE TABLE statements, or other specification of their schema) helps a lot.  And if you can't post pictures for it, post text (which is easier to copy for people to replicate your problem with anyway).  It is OK to leave out columns that are not relevant to the queries you are asking about (but indicate that there are other columns, eg with `-- ...etc...` as a comment where the columns would appear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand what you mean, but is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(factor*count) AS totalscore
FROM (
    SELECT
      p.id AS id,
      st.factor AS factor,
      COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM
      s2p_photo p 
      LEFT JOIN s2p_score s 
      LEFT JOIN s2p_score_type st 
    GROUP BY p.id, st.name
    ORDER BY p.id ASC
) AS baseview
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I know the original used LEFT JOIN, but why?  The SUM will ignore rows where one of the values (`factor` or `count`) is NULL, so you might as well use inner joins, I think.

Comment: Just wanted to leave as much of the OP's code intact as possible - the inner query is cut&paste. I thought this way I'd communicate not only a (possible) solution, but also how I derived it from the OP's initial work